# Why some of the jpeg images cannot be loaded in iPhone with old iOS version?

Tags: html, ios, css, image, jpeg

I am now testing my website with an old iPhone. Some of the images are not shown in the old iPhone. However, the images are shown properly in other devices. I have checked the image format of all images(wheater they can be shown in old iPhone or not) and all the images are in jpeg. Why did it happen?

Comment: You should produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem; otherwise we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

From another answer today: Try running this program on the images that work and don't work.

http://colosseumbuilders.com/sourcecode/jpegdump.zip

Check see what the difference is between the images that work and don't work.